# archiving outlook messages to local windows HDD

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving

I am using outlook via outlook.live.com in chrome. I have exceeded the allowed free storage.  I would like to archive some of the older messages to my local windows HDD which should reduce the storage used. A lot of sources mention going to the file tab etc. I have only 3 tabs - Home, View and Help.
How can I create the archive using this web route?

Comment: You need to pay more attention when reading your sources. Doing that you'd have understood what the answer says, i.e., you don't do it from the web, you do it from an email client locally installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup the online mails you need a mail client. Check [this Q/A](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-do-i-backup-my-emails-from-outlookcom/f6e54cf8-b8b6-49e9-8779-52f6c2b2ca34).

> if you aren't using Outlook desktop or another desktop email client,
> your options are limited to connecting the account to Gmail or yahoo
> and letting that account bring in copies your mail - or forward mail
> to another account.

> If you want a copy downloaded to your computer, you'll need to use an
> email client. The client built into Windows 10 would not be my
> recommendation though...

Answer (score 0):

OWA cannot store information directly locally，the Microsoft's recommended practice is save the message to OneDrive, here is the Blog:[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/storage-limits-in-outlook-com-7ac99134-69e5-4619-ac0b-2d313bba5e9e)
If you want to save the message to local, you need to use Outlook Client.